# Looping through a list and coloring the text as appropriate based on values

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a large list of names and scores from a survey. I am hoping there is a simple way to loop through the list and color the score red or green based on its value. I have successfully been able to color one of the values but my solution requires a lot of lines and I am hoping there is a quicker way to accomplish this other than copy and pasting the if elif else statements after each "_data" line, here is a snippet of the code:

`

```
one_frame['text'] = score.index[0]
one_data['text'] = score.iloc[0, 0]
if c_metric == 'Sleep' and score.iloc[0, 0] < 5 or c_metric != 'Sleep' and score.iloc[0, 0] <2.5:
    one_data.configure(fg='red')
elif c_metric == 'Sleep' and score.iloc[0, 0] > 5 or c_metric != 'Sleep' and score.iloc[0, 0] > 4:
    one_data.configure(fg='green')
else:
    one_data.configure(fg='white')
two_frame['text'] = score.index[1]
two_data['text'] = score.iloc[1, 0]
three_frame['text'] = score.index[2]
three_data['text'] = score.iloc[2, 0]
four_frame['text'] = score.index[3]
four_data['text'] = score.iloc[3, 0]
```

`

The data frame is 2 columns, a name and a score.

I have tried a few combination of a for loop but have not found the right solution to color the text appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this may be a unique issue but if anyone comes across a similar problem I have found a solution after a lot of trial and error:

I have added the score.iloc to a list, then under a new function looped through the list and colored as needed:

```
global avgs
avgs = []

try:
    one_frame['text'] = score.index[0]
    one_data['text'] = score.iloc[0, 0]
    avgs.append(score.iloc[0, 0])
    two_frame['text'] = score.index[1]
    two_data['text'] = score.iloc[1, 0]
    avgs.append(score.iloc[1, 0])
```

...

```
for i, k, g in zip(avgs, labs, fras):
    if c_metric == 'Sleep' and i < 6 or c_metric == 'RPE' and i > 15 or c_metric != 'Sleep' and c_metric != 'RPE' and i < 2.5:
        k.configure(fg='red')
        g.configure(fg='red')
    elif c_metric == 'Sleep' and i > 7 or c_metric == 'RPE' and i < 11 or c_metric != 'Sleep' and c_metric != 'RPE' and i > 4:
        k.configure(fg='green')
        g.configure(fg='green')
    else:
        k.configure(fg='white')
```

I also realize this is not the full code so if you do have any more questions I can explain a bit more and share the full code.

Good Luck!